# Laplace transform as a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

The Laplace transform is a linear mapping from the functions of time domain to frequency domain. The part $K(t,p)=e^{-pt}$ is called the kernel. The definition of kernel is the set which takes the transformed value to zero.. Now the question is how the $K(t,p)$ takes the zero value after transformation..?

Comment: It's ok in math to use the same word for different things.

Comment: Is the kernel in Laplace transform different from that of linear transformations??

Comment: The "kernel" in the Laplace transform is $e^{-pt}$, while the kernel of a linear transformation $T$ is the set of vectors $x$ such that $T(x)=0$.  These are two different things that happen to have the same name.

Comment: Kernel in Laplace transform is a special case of kernel in general integral transform. Yes, it different from that of linear transformations.